# Android adding text dynamically to a LinearLayout

Tags: android

I have the following LayoutFile

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Now i now to dynamically add multiple views to this layout. I am using the following code

```
View linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
            valueTV.setText("hallo hallo");
            valueTV.setId(5+i);
            valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV);
            linearLayout.invalidate();
        }
```

But i only can see the first item in the Layout ? What am i doing wrong ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

The first `TextView` is taking all the space.

Alternative choice by @Rob Meeuwisse, set your layout to vertical

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Moreover, you should not set id like this, create an ids.xml file in res/values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="tv1" />
    <item type="id" name="tv2" />
    <item type="id" name="tv3" />
    <item type="id" name="tv4" />
    <item type="id" name="tv5" />
    <item type="id" name="tv6" />
    <item type="id" name="tv7" />
    <item type="id" name="tv8" />
    <item type="id" name="tv9" />
    <item type="id" name="tv10" />
</resources>
```

And in your code :

```
try
{
    int key = R.id.class.getField("tv" + (i+1)).getInt(null);
    valueTV.setId(key);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // key does not exists, should not happen !
    // Do something about it
}
```

Comment: isn't it only filling the width, not the height?

Comment: good catch. or set the LinearLayout's orientation to vertical.